# ploting histogram and finding frequency from data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to plot histogram having data in such a way :

```
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
C
C
D
```

On x axis I want A,B,C... so on and on y axis I want frequency of times A,B,C occurred.
Can anyone suggest a way to find frequencies from data!!!

Comment: Base R: `barplot(table(data))`. To find the frequencies, `help('table')`. And it's a bar plot, not an histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot a bar plot from one categorical variable is as simple as

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

**Data**

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = "
A
A
A
B
B
C
C
C
C
C
D")

df1 <- data.frame(x)
```